# JTable Heder Height auto size

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtableheader

I'm working on a software with multiple languages. And german language needs column headers with a different height.

[image: Example screen]

As you can see on the screen, we can't read the text of the table headers.
But when I resize my JFrame (I resize the whole software (main Frame)), my headers are resized too ...

[image: Example with correct size]

But there is no code to resize the header height in the app. And I would like to reproduce this at the table creation. Because I don't want to force the user to resize the frame to see the entire headers. So how can I reproduce the header height without resizing the software frame ?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: `But when I resize my JFrame, my headers are resized too` Try invoking revalidate() and repaint on the table header (or table) after you change the text of the column headers.